# Modal in bootstrap not working after opening once

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I wonder what is the causes of this issue that after I opened the modal pop-up and clicking close button or cancel, next time I opened, the modal will not display. But it works fine when I will hit save button but not with close/cancel button. Is the `data-dismiss` function not working?

I have this code for closing the modal:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

and this also:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
```

When I clicked any of these button, the second around that I will clicked the modal will not displayed.

Here is my code:
Index.cshtml
     Add Airline

Calling modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Mondiale Modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog ml-modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                @* Content Inside Here *@
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>

Create.cshtml
@model Mondiale.Model.Airline

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div class="modalForm">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-fw"></i> New Airline</h4>
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Airlines", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "ajaxForm", data_target = ".modalForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="modal-body clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="panel panel-default panel-margin">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Airline Info</strong></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2 col-sm-3 control-label" })
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <span class="spinner pull-left"></span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default clear-cutomer-fld">Clear</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
'use strict';

(function ($) {

    /* Ajax Form Submit for Modal */
    var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {

        var $form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.spinner').addClass('fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x fa-fw');
            }
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));

            if (data.status == true) {
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
                location.reload();
            } else {
                $target.replaceWith(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

    /* Empty Modal Content on Hide */
    $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('.modal-content').empty();
        $('.modal-dialog').removeClass('modal-lg modal-sm');
    });

    $('.Airlines')
        .on('click', '.clear-cutomer-fld', function () { // onClick clear button on modal
            alert('clear');
            $('.ajaxForm')[0].reset();
        })
        .on('click', 'a[data-toggle="modal"]', function () { // show modal
            $('.modal-dialog').addClass($(this).attr('data-wrap'));
            $('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        })

        .on('submit', '.ajaxForm', ajaxFormSubmit); // modal ajax form submit

})(jQuery);
```

There's nothing wrong for adding the data but only for cancel/close button have an issue.

Comment: You should include your jquery code too.

Comment: Why are you removing modal-lg and modal-sm classes??